# Regex for a url pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm developing a dynamic controller which accept this urls:

1. mock_test5 - mock_test1
2. reviewer_test5
3. reviewer_test4
4. reviewer_test3.1
5. reviewer_test3.2
6. reviewer_test1

**Note:** reviewer_test2 is excluded

I'm having a hard time figuring it out. This is what I don't so far:

`^(mock|reviewer)_test[1-5]$`

I also don't know how do I interpret `3.1` and `3.2`

Comment: Are this all possible URLs?

Comment: If you need to check it against _exactly_ those 10 strings, why don't you just put them all in a `List` and use `contains`?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach yes that the all possible urls

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm using Spring MVC and as I said it is a URL pattern

Comment: should all elements that are not in this list fail? (Is it ok to have false-positives?)

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer yes

Comment: Why did I get -1? Can the one who down voted my post please explain it to me?

Comment: @newbie You do not seem to have spend time researching this yourself, you tried with what you already knew and then posted a question here, else you would easily figure out how to match "3.1" etc. -> Your question does not show research effort.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I see, I will keep that in mind next time. I just need to solve this fast because I have to refactor the code in 1hr. Also I'm new to regex. But thanks for the concern anyways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(?:mock_test[1-5]|reviewer_test(?:[145]|3[.][12]))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
^(?:mock_test(?:1|2|3|4|5)|reviewer_test(?:(?:1|4|5)|3\.(?:1|2)))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: I know it is off topic but I just want to know what did you use to generate that chart?

Comment: Why all the `?:` symbols?  I don't see what difference they make here.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Non capturing grouping save resources

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at this link: http://regexr.com?37dtn

```
^(mock_test[1-5])|reviewer_test([145]|3\.1|3\.2)$

^                  = start a line with
(mock_test[1-5])   = the string 'mock_test' followed by a number from 1 to 5 
                     I think the '(' and ')' are not necessary
|                  = OR
reviewer_test      = the string 'reviewer_test'
([145]|3\.1|3\.2)  = the numbers 1,4,5 OR the number 3.1 OR the number 3.2
$                  = end of line
```

---

#### Update:

If it is a limited number I wouldn't use a regex, because it seems to be some kind of `write once read never again` code.

Comment: doesn't match mock_test2

Comment: If I don't use regex to this. I will have to write 10 duplicate controllers with the same logic inside.

Comment: One last thing before I accept your answer. Can you explain a bit the regex so I can create similar in the future?